# What a '-' in TMPDIR do?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, env

I recently saw an example where a command was invoked with the following option passed to `env`:

```
TMPDIR="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}"
```

What does the `-` in `$TMPDIR` do? This was for an unspecified version of linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> ${*parameter*:-*word*}
>   If *parameter* is unset or null, the expansion of *word* is substituted. Otherwise, the value of *parameter* is substituted.

So this set `TMPDIR` to `/tmp` if it's empty or not set. If you leave out `:` (e.g. `${TMPDIR-/tmp}`, it only tests whether the variable is not set, as specified:

> Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset. Put another way, if the colon is included, the operator tests for both parameter’s existence and that its value is not null; if the colon is omitted, the operator tests only for existence.

Answer (score 2):

[It sets `$TMPDIR` to itself if it's set, otherwise it sets it to `/tmp`.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#DEFPARAM1)